# Increment in Shiny numericInput is 2 despite step = 1 in macOS Catalina

Tags: r, macos, shiny, numeric-input

Assume you have a `numericInput` in your Shiny application.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(numericInput(
    "input",
    "n",
    value = 2,
    min = 2,
    max = 10,
    step = 1
))
shinyApp(ui, function(input, output) {
    observe({
        str(input$hadley)
    })
})
```

If you run this application and click the up or down arrow within the `numericInput` box, it will increment by steps of twice the value in `step`. Did I miss something when I use `numericInput`?

Session info

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.6.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5       crayon_1.3.4     digest_0.6.27    withr_2.3.0      later_1.1.0.1    mime_0.9        
 [7] R6_2.5.0         jsonlite_1.7.1   lifecycle_1.0.0  xtable_1.8-4     magrittr_2.0.1   cachem_1.0.4    
[13] rlang_0.4.10     rstudioapi_0.13  promises_1.2.0.1 jquerylib_0.1.3  bslib_0.2.4      ellipsis_0.3.1  
[19] tools_4.0.3      httpuv_1.5.5     fastmap_1.1.0    compiler_4.0.3   htmltools_0.5.1  sass_0.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that it has been reported a [bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6953) and seems this is only an issue in macOS.

One of the solutions mentioned by [NickPyll](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6953#issuecomment-645358681) (which is, of course, obvious) is to set `step` to half your actual step.  At least for now it works in my application.